# Limit problem where the equation is not explicitly given

Tags: calculus, limits

In all the examples I've had for limits I have always been given a limit to solve. Working through some old examination papers I found this.

$1 \le f(x) \le x^2 + 6x + 6$ for all $x$, find $ \lim \limits_{x \to -1} f(x)$

What I am thinking is that this is an application of the Squeeze theorem and that if I solve $\lim \limits_{x \to -1} x^2 + 6x + 6$ I can deduce that $\lim \limits_{x \to -1} f(x) = 1$

Does this seem correct?

Comment: You can't say that $f(x) = 1$, but you can use the squeeze theorem to conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -1}f(x) = 1$.

Comment: $1\leqslant\lim\limits_{x\to-1}f(x)\leqslant6$. Isn't it?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -1}(6x^2+6x+6) = 6 \neq 1$, we can't conclude anything about $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -1}f(x)$. (Not even if it exists).

Comment: I did not understand the comments and then realized I made a typo in the formula. Sorry about that.

Comment: Now that you have fixed the typo, you can in fact use the squeeze theorem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}1&\xrightarrow[x\to -1]{}1\\{}\\x^2+6x+6&\xrightarrow[x\to -1]{}(-1)^2+6(-1)+6=1\end{align*}$$

Thus, and since **it is given** that $\;1\le f(x)\le x^2+6x+6\;$ , we can apply the squeeze theorem and get

$$\lim_{x\to -1}f(x)=1$$

Pay attention to the fact that it is enough to have that $\;1\le f(x)\le x^2+6x+6\;$ in some neighborhood of $\;-1\;$ , i.e. in $\;(-1-\epsilon\,,\,-1+\epsilon)\;,\;\epsilon>0\;$  . To require "for all $\;x$" is way too much.